# Google spreadsheet: calculate start and end rownumber of first non-empty range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column `B` which may have a value `1` or is empty.

I want to calculate 2 fields:

- `startFirstRange`: the start rownumber of the first non-empty range, or -1 if not exist.
- `endFirstRange`: the end rownumber of the first non-empty range, or 0 if not exist.

I've managed to get `startFirstRange` as follows:

```
 =ArrayFormula(MIN(IFERROR(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!B2:B),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2:B))),-1)))
```

Naively, I tried the following to get `endFirstRange`:

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!B:B),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B:B)))))
```

However, this results in the end rownumber of the **last** non-empty range, instead of the end rownumber of the **first** non-empty range.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attempt (there may well be a shorter way):

For `startFirstRange`, lets say invoked in `A1`:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!B2:B),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2:B))),-1),1)
```

Then for `endFirstRange`, which will reference the result of startFirstRange in `A1`:

```
=IF(A1=-1,0,IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!B2:B)-1,ROW(Sheet1!B2:B)>A1,ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2:B)),1),ROWS(Sheet1!B:B)))
```

Comment: Tested. Works splendid! Cheers. (btw: see small edit)

Comment: Thanks mate; I have approved the edit, but not enough rep to edit it in myself. Although I think your edit has "Sheet!" rather than "Sheet1!".

Comment: Redid edit. shweet!